# Cursor shape under vim + tmux

Tags: tmux, cygwin

How can I have different cursor shapes when running vim inside tmux under cygwin?

WITHOUT tmux these lines would be enough to achieve what I want:

```
let &t_SI = "\e[5 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"
```

But somehow my tmux breaks it - cursor has block shape no matter what vim mode I'm in.

**My specs:**

- Windows 7 x64
- Cygwin x86
- TMUX 1.9a
- Vim 7.4.726 (compiled with +cursorshape)
- terminal emulator: mintty 1.1.3
- used in Cygwin Terminal or Cmder (either way, cursor shapes work only without TMUX)
- `echo $TERM` gives me `screen-256color` (in TMUX and outside of it, because i have `export TERM=screen-256color` in my `.bashrc`
- `.tmux.conf` contains:
  `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
  setw -g xterm-keys on`

**What i tried already** without success:

- `export TERM=xterm`
- `export TERM=vt100`
- "rightclick on bar > Options > Looks > Cursor" (it changes the cursor permanently, vim modes still don't change it)

Comment: Vim compiled with '+cursorshape' feature?

Comment: Check terminal  settings. And this question looks similar 
 http://superuser.com/questions/634326/how-can-i-get-a-block-cursor-in-vim-in-the-cygwin-terminal

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? Have you tried something like `let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1;BlinkingCursorEnabled=1\x7\<Esc>\\"` and `let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0;BlinkingCursorEnabled=0\x7\<Esc>\\"`?

Comment: @jjaderberg iTerm's escape sequence? Works only in iTerm with some cautions:  
[iTerm Doc](https://iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html)  
>iTerm2 supports several non-standard escape codes. These may not work properly in tmux or screen, and may have unknown effects on other terminal emulators. Proceed with caution.

Comment: @alex-kroll I was not aware that it was iTerm specific. My point was that the control sequence may need to be altered when using tmux, and that how to alter it may depend on the terminal emulator (and "here's an example ...") What part of that sequence is peculiar to iTerm, btw? I thought I saw precisely or very similar sequences used for other terms, though I may be mistaken.

Comment: @jjaderberg btw `let &t_SI = "\e[5 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"` `let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"` works fine for me.
Windows7x64, vim 7.4, mintty + tmux.

Comment: @AlexKroll The solution to the other question doesn't work for me (because of TMUX). Mintty setting: "rightclick on bar > Options > Looks > Cursor" is not a solution either, because it changes the cursor permanently (vim modes still don't change the cursor).

Comment: @jjaderberg It doesn't work, even without tmux (also tried replacing "\<Esc>" with "\e"). The next three "lets" work only outside of tmux.

Comment: I updated the question with additional information.

Comment: I've check my soft one more time and all versions are same with yours but $TERM in mintty options is `xterm-256color` inside tmux `screen-256color`. tmux has version 1.9 (and your is 1.9a). I've launch vim inside tmux `vim -u NULL` (-u NULL means no config). Cursor shape is block in any mode, but when I assign `t_SI` and `t_EI` shape switch from block (normal mode) to `I` (insert mode) as expected. Can you try to launch vim with empty .vimrc, without any colorschemes and plugins?

Comment: @AlexCroll - i renamed my ```.bashrc```, ```.tmux.conf``` and left only two variabls in ```.vimrc``` = it works now! i will be restoring my configuration and will let you know what caused the problems.

Comment: @AlexCroll - The problem was caused by this line in my ```.bashrc```: ```export TERM=screen-256color```. If i comment the line out or change its value to for example "xterm-256color", cursor changing in different vim modes in tmux works again! Maybe tmux thought it is running inside screen? You can add this as an answer so i can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the problem is that tmux doesn't send your cursor-changing escape codes to the terminal emulator. You need to wrap your desired escape codes in a special sequence that tells tmux that it should pass it on to the outer terminal.

The sequence you need to wrap your escape sequence in is `\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc> ... \<Esc>\\`([Source](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/1322)). The `...` is your escape sequence.

So, try doing something like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
if exists('$TMUX')
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\e[5 q\<Esc>\\"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\e[2 q\<Esc>\\"
else
    let &t_SI = "\e[5 q"
    let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"
endif
```

I don't use your terminal emulator or cygwin, so I couldn't test this code. But the method worked for me (I just wrapped other escape codes that suit my terminal).

Comment: This is even better - works without changing my ```.bashrc```. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The correct value of `$TERM` environments variable is very important. Make sure that it is different from `screen-256color`. Set it to `xterm-256color` for example.

Comment: A cleaner solution than the accepted one.