# Vim normal and insert mode cursor not changing in GNU screen

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, cursor

I use vim in a few different contexts; typically, I like to put this in my `.vimrc`:

```
let &t_ti.="\<Esc>[1 q"
let &t_SI.="\<Esc>[5 q"
let &t_EI.="\<Esc>[1 q"
let &t_te.="\<Esc>[0 q"
```

This makes it so that insert and normal mode use different cursors (normal mode is a block cursor and insert mode is a vertical line). This works for me in mintty with cygwin, xterm, and also rvxt just fine. However, whenever I use GNU screen, my cursor no longer changes. I've seen references to fixing this for tmux (for instance here: [Cursor shape under vim + tmux](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/cursor-shape-under-vim-tmux)), but nothing I've tried for Screen has worked. For now, I'm using this in my `.vimrc`:

```
"Underline currently edited line
if !has("gui_running")
    :autocmd InsertEnter * set cul
    :autocmd InsertLeave * set nocul
endif
```

That makes it so that when in insert mode the current line is underlined (the `:has("gui_running")` prevents it from taking effect in gvim). I also use `set laststatus=2` to keep the status bar on the bottom, which also helps. I just wish it worked a bit more like gvim. Has anyone found a fix for this?

Comment: Seems I can't move it myself at my n00b rep (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site), but I'm totally up for it being moved (I didn't realize there was a Vi channel; cheers for that!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I figured it out, although I don't totally understand the fix. This appears to work for mintty, xterm, and rxvt:

```
" Set up vertical vs block cursor for insert/normal mode
if &term =~ "screen."
    let &t_ti.="\eP\e[1 q\e\\"
    let &t_SI.="\eP\e[5 q\e\\"
    let &t_EI.="\eP\e[1 q\e\\"
    let &t_te.="\eP\e[0 q\e\\"
else
    let &t_ti.="\<Esc>[1 q"
    let &t_SI.="\<Esc>[5 q"
    let &t_EI.="\<Esc>[1 q"
    let &t_te.="\<Esc>[0 q"
endif
```

This leans on your screenrc having something like "term screen" or "term screen-256color" so that the vimrc file can identify which terminal you're on. The only remaining terminal I use regularly where this *doesn't* work is PuTTY, but I think it literally doesn't support terminal commands to change the cursor shape. Mintty was forked from PuTTY a while back, and I saw here (https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2009-07/msg00011.html) that DECSCUSR support was added to mintty after that fork.

This is good enough for me - if I'm ssh'ing into a machine where I really want my block cursor in Vim, I guess I can either cygwin/ssh or PuTTY/XMing/rxvt my way through it instead of PuTTY.

Comment: For me, `echo &term` outputs `screen` so I changed the regexp in the line starting `if &term ...` to `screen.*`.

Comment: @KennyEvitt same for me on MacOS. Good catch!

Comment: Thanks! Your code works for me! Windows 10, mintty 3.4.7 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)

Comment: This seems to work! It looks like it uses the "Device Control String; Outputs a string directly to the host" to output the usual escape codes per https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html

Comment: Still saving my sanity, eight years later!